# My footer is not centered, pushed to the right

Tags: html, css, footer

On mobile, it looks fine, as expected. However, the footer on the bottom is not centered and is pushed to the right despite me using both `<center>` and `text-align: center;`

https://4qluxigz.apps.lair.io/ Here's the link (hosted by Source Lair, which is the meaning of the weird link).

Any help would be appreciated as it's probably because of a mistake I made!

Edit: Part for footer

```
<div class="footer">
        <div class="inFooter">
            <center>
            <p class="copy">
            © 2016 Joey Yelkich. All rights reserved
        </p>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>

.footer {
background-color: #EEEEEE;
text-align: center;
color: white;
display: block;
text-align: center;
```

}

```
.copy {
    color: #000;
word-spacing: 2px;
display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
padding: 4px 25px 4px 20px;
background: #fff;
text-align: center;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: FYI, don't use the `<center>` tag ever for anything, except for when telling people not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `clear: both` on `.footer`, this will work for both desktop as well as mobile. Like:

```
.footer {
  clear: both;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @yelkish Hope, this solved your problem. If it has solved your problem don't forget to upvote & accept this as your answer.